# Trying to multipy but its only multiplying .10 to any input I type in. Also for my Scanner "resource" says its never closed

Tags: java, if-statement

I am working on this "if else" statement to multiply a range of numbers but it only multiplies to .10
Not sure what I am doing wrong. Additionally for "resource" it says its never closed.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
public class taxableIncome {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        {
        Scanner resource = new Scanner(System.in); //scanner object for keyboard input.
        System.out.print("Enter annual income:  "); 
        {
        
        int input = 0; 
        double ten = .10; // 10% tax 
        double fifthteen = .15; // 15% tax 
        double twentyfive = .25;
        double twentyeight = .28;
        double thirtythree = .33;
        double thirtyfive = .35;
        double total = 0.0;
        boolean taxes = true;
        
        while(taxes)
        {
        if (input >= 0 && input <= 8500){
                total = ten * resource.nextDouble();
                System.out.println("The taxable annual income is $" + total + "\nThank you very much.");
        }else if  (input >= 8500 && input <= 34500){
                    total = fifthteen * resource.nextDouble();
                    System.out.println("The taxable annual income is $" + total + "\nThank you very much.");
                    } else if (input >= 34500 && input <= 83600){
                        total = twentyfive * resource.nextDouble();
                        System.out.println("The taxable annual income is $" + total + "\nThank you very much.");
                        }else if (input >= 83600 && input <= 174400){
                            total = twentyeight * resource.nextDouble();
                            System.out.println("The taxable annual income is $" + total + "\nThank you very much.");
                        }else if (input >= 174400 && input <= 379150){
                            total = thirtythree * resource.nextDouble();
                            System.out.println("The taxable annual income is $" + total + "\nThank you very much.");
                        }else if (input >= 379150 && input >= 379151) {
                            total = thirtyfive * resource.nextDouble();
                            System.out.println("The taxable annual income is $" + total + "\nThank you very much.");
                            taxes = false;
                        } 
                            
                        
        }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: If you are expecting single input from user,  move **resource.nextDouble()*** out of while Loop

Comment: Glad to see you trying to participate on Stack Overflow. A few points: (a) Learn to format your code properly using either triple back-ticks or indenting 4 spaces. (b) Use proper English, not abbreviated chat room lingo. (c) Omit chit-chat and "Need help" phrases. (d) Hone your title to briefly summarize your specific technical issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is always evaluating for input == 0.0 because at no point does the code update this value. The program also never terminates for this reason as well.

Comment: How would I update this value?

Answer (score 0):

Your `input` variable is initialized to 0.0, therefore it will always enter the first if statement and multiply by 0.10.
Take the salary input out of the if statements so the if statements will check based on your inputs.